# Problem using proxy-agent with AWS and nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, proxy

I am trying to add proxy support to a working AWS pollyspeech program written in nodejs. Using docs from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/node-configuring-proxies.html my code looks like this:

```
    var proxy = require('proxy-agent');

    AWS.config.update({

         httpOptions: { agent: proxy('https://XX XX.XX.XX:XXXX') }
    });

    var Polly = new AWS.Polly({
       region: cfg_region,
       accessKeyId: cfg_accessKeyId,
       secretAccessKey: cfg_secretAccessKey
    });
```

When executing, I see this:

TypeError: proxy is not a function

The value of proxy after the require() is:

```
{
  proxies: {
    http: [ [Function], [Function] ],
    https: [ [Function], [Function] ],
    socks: [ [Function], [Function] ],
    socks4: [ [Function], [Function] ],
    socks4a: [ [Function], [Function] ],
    socks5: [ [Function], [Function] ],
    socks5h: [ [Function], [Function] ],
    'pac-data': [ [Function], [Function] ],
    'pac-file': [ [Function], [Function] ],
    'pac-ftp': [ [Function], [Function] ],
    'pac-http': [ [Function], [Function] ],
    'pac-https': [ [Function], [Function] ]
  },
  ProxyAgent: [class ProxyAgent extends Agent]
}
```

The node version is v18.16.0.
The proxy agent is proxy-agent@6.2.1

I've tried various other proxies but haven't made them work with AWS.

Can some one suggest a fix?

Thanks

Comment: To fix this, I down graded to proxy-agent@5.0.0. Not the best solution, but until a better one comes along....

Answer (score 0):

I believe the interface is updated. Try

```
const {ProxyAgent} = require('proxy-agent');
AWS.config.update({
  httpOptions: {agent: new ProxyAgent()}
});
```